# Webpage design/ Web programming

Tags: html

I am designing a web page for a client of mine.  I am having problems with making the right side of the page be at the same level as the left side of my page.  I am trying to make the right side be at the top of the page.  I have tried a few tricks but nothing seems to be working. I don't want the right to be locked necessarily I just want to be up.  Right now the right side is lingering at the bottom of the page.  the file is at www.bussmanncomputers.net/Jara.  Please help me!!!

Comment: Include the code that is causing you problems. In this case the html and the css that illustrate the issue.  If you can trim it down to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the problem, that will make it easier for people to help you.  Making a jsfiddle of the problem is also helpful  because people can play with it to come up with a solution.  Your website will change as soon as you have the solution, so a link to your website doesn't help people in the future.

Comment: I am not sure what part of the code is causing the problem, but here is a copy of my css, the part that is being problematic:#rightside    { float: right; width: 200px; height: 300px; clear: both; }  The only reason why I put the website in there is so that someone could look at the code and see if I should have something different.

Answer (score 0):

This question requires a book to answer. A good place to start would be with a HTML/CSS layout tutorial. Try [one of these](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=html%20layout%20tutorial).

There are a lot of ways to do what you want to do.

The best way is to use flexbox display.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class='left'>
    </div>
    <div class='right'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    display: flex;
}
.left {
    flex: 3;
}
.right {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Another way is to use `float: left;` on both of the columns.